# R: how to initialize empty binary tree?

Tags: r, arrays, list

I want to initialize an object that has the structure of a complete binary tree so that I can use it to store the node values. Let's suppose I specify a tree with depth `d = 3`, then I would have 1 root node at level 1, 2 nodes at level 2, and 4 nodes at level 3.

[image]

Would a list be a good way to store this? Maybe an array if that's computationally better? For a potential list, I was thinking it would look something like this for `d = 3`:

```
>empty_tree
[[1]]
[1]

[[2]]
[1]
[2]

[[3]]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
```

Comment: Maybe something in *igraph* can deal with this? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/ "*Routines for simple graphs and network analysis. It can handle large graphs very well and provides functions for generating random and regular graphs, graph visualization, centrality methods and much more.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you need something like below

```
empty_tree <- function(d) sapply(1:d, function(k) replicate(2**(k-1),c()))
```

such that

```
> empty_tree(2)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]]
NULL


> empty_tree(3)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]]
NULL


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
NULL

[[3]][[2]]
NULL

[[3]][[3]]
NULL

[[3]][[4]]
NULL
```